# What was the conversation in French, American Crime Season 2

Tags: plot-explanation, american-crime

In *American Crime* season 3, episode 6.

Nicholas Coates is playing table pool with his friends while berating his wife for hiring a French speaking nanny, not working a job and writing a check to a charity.

Soon after, his wife, Clair Coates, speaks something in French to a lady, who appears to be shocked upon hearing it.

What does Clair say in French?

Comment: Can you find a clip of this scene?

Comment: @John, I will see what I can do after I go home. The worst scenario is to make a video clip and upload it onto YouTube then refer it here.

Comment: @John, I found the answer, it was explained at the end of the season.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

- It is discovered at the end of season 3, Clair says something like: "My husband is so impotent that he cannot get me pregnant"